# Возможно ли смоделировать в русском истинно "Yoda style", чтоб он звучал так же страннейше как в английском?

Tags: перевод, выражения, морфология, английский

По-моему, это невозможно - смоделировать в русском истинно "Yoda style", чтоб он звучал так же страннейше (полагаю, не ошибаюсь) как в английском.

Учитывая, что русский - язык флективно-синтетический с безразличным порядком слов в предложениях.

[image: https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-14.jpg]

[image]

[image]

Я имею в виду, это вряд ли вообще возможно - передать в русском именно тот уровень "йодистости" и странности, что, наверное, существует в английском для именно таких случаев. За счёт лишь перестановки слов во флективно-синтетическом языке, порядок слов в сентенциях коего, в общем-то, не важен. В отличие от.

https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2015/12/hmmmmm/420798

Comment: I think your examples look OK already. One just have to stick to some consistent placement scheme. The first one is weaker in that regard, but the third is OK.

Comment: alamar... there are just usual Russian phrases really. Or 95%-usual... :>

Comment: Пример про яблоко не аутентичен. Скорее "Яблоко, есть у меня". Он очень близкую фразу говорит в приквеле. Чего-то не хватает. Какой-то дефиниции к яблоку.

Answer (score 1):

Закономерность в Йодином порядке слов есть. [Рему впереди темы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) ставит он. Не осознавая сами того, делают и подражатели его так. Удается вполне оттого и по-русски эту особенность передать.

Comment: В английском его порядок менее.. ненормален, на самом деле.  Это заблуждение советской школы, что английский язык настолько формален. Фразы Йоды смахивает на стихосложение и правила языка в принципе это позволяют, только обычно это используется в сложноподчиненных предложениях. Напоминаю, что а в английском языке запятая разделяет сложные предложения в тех случаях, когда союз  не находится между ними. Рема и тема в стихосложении иногда переворачивались и тоже разделялись запятой. Таким образом он звучит загадочнее, как будто говоря загадками в каждой фразе, потому как фраза начинается с ремы.

Comment: @Swift Я в курсе, со школьных вполне-таки лет, про "much have I travelled in the realms of gold" и про "Glamis thou art, and Cawdor, and shalt be // What thou art promised". Тем не менее, когда Марк Окранд придумывал клингон (в 1984 году, уже после экранного дебюта Йоды), он избрал порядок слов OVS специально чтоб было как можно менее привычно.  Поэтому и слишком вписывать Йоду в английский культурный контекст не стоит. Отголосок поэтической речи там, безусловно, есть, но до него ум доискивается уже после того, как столкнулся с чем-то неожиданно-неестественным. И переводы должны это отражать.

Comment: Да хоть "To be, or not to be, that is the question".  Или современный мем "Why, how thicc thou art" :) Скорее, контекст всей германской группы, они все имеют возможножность к такому.   Да и целый ряд источников - лингвистов и носителей языка - утверждает, что его фразы грамматически верны как минимум. Ряд известных максим в оригинале имеют инвертированный порядок. В нем есть элемент помпезности и он встречается не только в поэзии но и в официальных заявлениях, эпистолярном жанре или речах. На мой взгляд, в большинстве случаев они легко переводятся на русский. Но всеравно, +1.

Comment: @Swift Йода все-таки прежде всего инопланетянин — или, если расширить архетип, экзотический чужеземец. Поэтому при переводе стоит сохранять некую блуждающую (псевдо)случайность стилистических регистров, в которые он попадает из-за интерференции условного своего языка. А это требует определенной тонкости в подходе.

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке порядок слов в предложении может меняться, но это не калейдоскоп, каждое такое изменение меняет смысл и интонационное наполнение высказывания.

Йода просто-напросто может использовать такой порядок слов, который создаёт диссонанс между тем, как сказано, и тем, что сказано в действительности.

Например, "грамотность не переоцени свою" совершенно допустимое высказывание, если оно восклицается "в проброс", но как часть сложносочинённого предложения оно диссонирует.

Важно придерживаться какой-то одной схемы. Например, на последней картинке "латинский" (или "корейский") порядок слов, где глагол в конце предложения, который нехарактерен именно для русского языка. Предположительно, Йода не путает слова местами из-за дизлексии, а просто имеет свой собственный логичный идиолект.

Comment: "каждое такое изменение меняет смысл и интонационное наполнение высказывания." - не сильно-то и меняет, а интонация это вообще отдельный вопрос... когда как вообщем. Йода просто напросто говорит на языке (на англ.) - где порядок слов воистину важен жизненно, но у нас не так :> Мы уже говорим на почти йодистом языке - или он включает в  себя это. 
" как часть сложносочинённого предложения оно диссонирует."- да ничуть... Все это может добавлять поэзии или пафоса в стиле какого-нибудь волхва вещающего, но это не является чужеродным настолько... В общем, мне кажется, это не то...

Comment: Я погуглил "yoda quotes", и 95% из них никаких строгих правил английского языка не нарушают. Не больше, чем Киплинг в своей поэме If.

Comment: " "латинский" (или "корейский") порядок слов, где глагол в конце предложения, который нехарактерен именно для русского языка."  - у нас нет определенного порядка слов. Есть превалирующий (SVO), так сказать - но это совсем не то же самое. В языке слов порядка нашем такого нет, сказать бы мог о котором ты - "русский порядок".

Comment: Я погуглил "yoda quotes", - вон там статья выше...

Comment: " В языке слов порядка нашем нет" - и он нам и не нужен вовсе. Потому что язык - флективный :>

Comment: Там же и написано, что высказывания Йоды напоминают пословицы-поговорки. Это вполне существующие в английском языке формы.

Comment: архаичные скорее всего :> а чем в английском архаичнее - тем ближе к флективности исходной :>

Comment: В русском языке порядочно вариантов архаичного размещения слов, почитать Державина или Ломоносова и переложить на Йоду

Comment: и русская архаичность - совсем не то что английская. Большинство не понимает даже английский времен Шекспира, как я слыхал :>

Comment: и наш язык свой строй не менял. Как был флективный так и есть :> Так что в порядках там тем более ничего особо архаичного нет

Comment: @Пилум английский Шеспира - это как русский времён Ивана Грозного...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы смоделировать в русском истинно "Yoda style", возможно, кроме порядка, нужно еще формы слов менять или что-то еще, что критично для русского языка. Типа: горазд слова переставляя ты, но йодой смочь не станешь ты.

Comment: Это звучит непонятно и грамматически неверно, что уже проблема. А вот выбор слов из облака синонимов может быть важен.